# Securing an endpoint differently based on the type of a call. Api key authenticateon requires a special role additionally

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, jwt

I have an endpoint that I need to secure differently based on the way the endpoint is called.

If I annotated the endpoint just with `@Secured("MYROLE")` it will apply regardless of whether it was called with the user/password or it was an api key call. Additionally, there is only some endpoints that need a special ROLE to be called with api key.

I am asking rather in general how to handle the different combinations of security restrictions. Is that a filter that I have to implement, but how do I pass the information that the endpoint called needs that special role check?

or is the better way to somehow ignore the `MYROLE` for all calls, but for the ones authenticated with api key.

Comment: Why do you need different roles for different authentications? That looks like a xy problem.

Comment: Don't use `@Secured` but use `@PreAuthorize` with ` access('rule1 or rule2')` to write your security expressions. Those are way more powerful then just a role/authority check.